# How can I get SQL Server database properties from C# code?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, database-connection, readonly-attribute

I've a C# 4.0 console application and a SQL Server 2008 database up and running on database server.

Does somebody know if there is a way to get the database properties (like "Database Read-Only" ) from the C# code?

My guess is it should be, but I was not able to find out the accurate solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it. One is to use the [Database Metadata tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188233.aspx) the other to use [SQL Management objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) in both cases there's lot of data there so you really need to know what you want. For example this is how you would get the "Database Read-Only" property you mentioned.

**Using a SqlCommand against the MetaData**

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT is_read_only FROM sys.filegroups",cnn);
   cnn.Open();
   var isReadOnly = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   Console.WriteLine(isReadOnly );
}
```

**Using SMO**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace SMO_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Server srv = new Server(); //Connection to the local SQL Server 

            Database db = srv.Databases["master"];
            foreach (FileGroup fg in db.FileGroups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fg.ReadOnly);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally used the MetaData approach but changed the SqlCommand line to: "SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DatabaseNameHere', 'Updateability')", myConnection);" and it works perfectly. Thanks for your contribution.